# In a desktop, the 5v from USB come directly from the PSU 5v or the motherboard intervenes?

Tags: usb, motherboard, power-supply

I have a regular desktop computer with an ATX power supply and a Micro-ATX motherboard (Asus H81M-K). I have this doubt if the motherboard intervenes in some way regarding the 5v of the USB. Even with my computer turned off backpanel USB still has power but the frontpanel USB doesn´t.

Answer (score 2):

The PSU provides power to the motherboard and the motherboard provides power to all USB devices.  Modern computers are never 100% "off," Many motherboards still provide power to USB ports, even when in a low power, or "off" state.  Typically, these "always on" ports are colored yellow, like below.

[image]

However, this is often not always the case, as many manufacturers ignore color coding these ports.  Why?  Not sure.  Perhaps it adds additional cost, or it ruins the visual aesthetic.

Computers still need power to recognize that you hit the power button, to turn back on after a power outage, to power USB devices, and many other reasons.  Modern hardware and operating systems use [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) to manage these power settings.

Comment: @Tiago The PSU provides 3.3v, 5v, and 12v to the motherboard.

Comment: Yellow-colored (and orange) ports usually used to designate "charging ports", which are ports with special circuitry to provide "charging signature" of various kinds when the system is in standby, and usually have contacts with enhanced current rating.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Intel's guide to USB design](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/hs_usb_pdg_r1_0.pdf), when a PC system is on AC power but in standby (soft off), the USB ports receive their power from +5VSB (always ON) power, which is built into every ATX12V PSU. It is designed so a USB peripheral (keyboard, mouse) can wake the computer up. This is a common USB framework, and the ports don't have any requirement to be colored in any special way.

When the system is active, it is recommended that USB port power gets switched to standard +5V rail, providing more power. And a system designer can choose which ports are powered by this schema, and which are active only in system ON mode.

Apparently the mobo ports follow the recommendation to switch back to standby power (motherboard "intervenes"), while the front ports are connected to headers that don't do this switch.